# 二つのデータフレームの比較

Tags: python, pandas

以下のような二つのデータフレームdf1,df2があり、df2はdf1の要素を内容である程度整理したものです。df1にはあってdf2には含まれていない要素で新たな列を作り付け加えたいです。

```
import pandas as pd
df1 = pd.DataFrame([["Jack","Male","USA",20,"mucsician","rock","movie"],
               ["Mary","Female","Canada","game",24,"unemployed","None"],
               ["Marco",25,"Italy","designer","fashion","tennis","None"],
               ["Isabel","Female","France",24,"shopping","actress","None"]])
```

df1の出力結果

```
      0       1       2       3         4          5           6
0   Jack    Male     USA     20      musician     rock       movie
1   Mary    Female  Canada   game      24       unemployed    None
2   Marco    25     Italy   designer fashion     tennis       None
3   Isabel  Female  France   24      shopping    actress      None

df2 = pd.DataFrame([["Jack","Male","USA",20,"mucsician"],
               ["Mary","Female","Canada",24,"unemployed"],
               ["Marco","None","Italy",25,"designer"],
               ["Isabel","Female","France",24,"actress"]])
```

df2の出力結果

```
      0      1       2      3       4
0   Jack    Male    USA     20  mucsician
1   Mary    Female  Canada  24  unemployed
2   Marco   None    Italy   25  designer
3   Isabel  Female  France  24  actress
```

理想は以下のように列5, 6でdf2にはなかった要素を付け加える形です

```
      0       1       2      3      4        5       6
0   Jack    Male    USA     20  musician    rock    movie
1   Mary    Female  Canada  24  unemployed  game    None
2   Marco   None    Italy   25  designer    fashion tennis
3   Isabel  Female  France  24  actress    shopping  None
```

一列ずつ比べるなら、df2に含まれている要素を列ごとにリスト(list)にして、df1にはカラム名を作り、df1[df1['col_name'].isin(value_list)]のような感じかなと思ったのですが、これだと列がたくさんある場合時間がかかりすぎてしまいます。なにか上手い方法はないでしょうか？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

こんな感じでどうでしょうか？

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame([["Jack","Male","USA",20,"mucsician","rock","movie"],
               ["Mary","Female","Canada","game",24,"unemployed","None"],
               ["Marco",25,"Italy","designer","fashion","tennis","None"],
               ["Isabel","Female","France",24,"shopping","actress","None"]])

df2 = pd.DataFrame([["Jack","Male","USA",20,"mucsician"],
               ["Mary","Female","Canada",24,"unemployed"],
               ["Marco","None","Italy",25,"designer"],
               ["Isabel","Female","France",24,"actress"]])

ret = pd.concat([df2, df1], axis=1).apply(lambda d: d.drop_duplicates().reset_index(drop=True), axis=1)
print(ret)
#         0       1       2   3           4         5       6
# 0    Jack    Male     USA  20   mucsician      rock   movie
# 1    Mary  Female  Canada  24  unemployed      game    None
# 2   Marco    None   Italy  25    designer   fashion  tennis
# 3  Isabel  Female  France  24     actress  shopping    None
```

Comment: いつも回答ありがとうございます！今回も完璧にできました。isinは使わずにデータにダブりがあるか(duplicate)を見るのですね(^ ^)